# Am i able to get the description and status of a project in Asana usin an api key?

Tags: asana

I've retrieved all the projects from a certain workspace and the tasks associated with them using an Api key in C#, but now I'm wondering how would I go about getting the descriptions and statuses of these projects?

Answer (score 0):

The description is in the "notes" field of the project - we don't currently expose the status, but we're hoping to in future.

Comment: Hello, is there an estimated time for when the side bar for the project will be accessible?

Comment: Sorry, it's not on our immediate roadmap currently. That said, we do prioritize to some extent based on a notion of how popular requests are - in this case, the question has 0 upvotes, which doesn't indicate strong demand (we also consider things like requests to API support and so forth, as well as how important the feature is relative to other things on the roadmap).